# Передача данных между потоками POCO C++ Libraries

Tags: c++, многопоточность, poco

Использую TCPServer (POCO C++ Libraries), который создает поток на 1 клиента.

Необходимо передавать клиенту(потоку), к примеру, данные о передвижении персонажей в игровом мире.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Как я понял нужно  использовать события. Один поток кладет, другой читает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи между потоками в POCO существует класс [NotificationQueue](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.NotificationQueue.html). Я добавил вывод информационных сообщений в пример [отсюда](https://pocoproject.org/slides/090-NotificationsEvents.pdf) и перевел комментарии:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Poco/Notification.h"
#include "Poco/NotificationQueue.h"
#include "Poco/ThreadPool.h"
#include "Poco/Runnable.h"
#include "Poco/AutoPtr.h"
using Poco::Notification;
using Poco::NotificationQueue;
using Poco::ThreadPool;
using Poco::Runnable;
using Poco::AutoPtr;
class WorkNotification: public Notification
    {
    public:
        WorkNotification(int data): _data(data) {}
        int data() const
            {
            return _data;
            }
    private:
        int _data;
    };

class Worker: public Runnable
    {
    public:
        Worker(NotificationQueue& queue,
            const std::string& str): _queue(queue),name(str) {}
        void run()
            {
            AutoPtr<Notification> pNf(_queue.waitDequeueNotification());
            while (pNf)
                {
                WorkNotification* pWorkNf =
                    dynamic_cast<WorkNotification*>(pNf.get());
                if (pWorkNf)
                    {
                    std::cout<<name<<" get data : "<<pWorkNf->data()<<"\n";
                    }
                pNf = 
                    _queue.waitDequeueNotification();
                }
            }
    private:
        NotificationQueue& _queue;
        std::string name;
    };

int main()
    {
    NotificationQueue queue;
    //создаем рабочие процессы
    Worker worker1(queue,"first"); 
    Worker worker2(queue,"second");
    // запускаем
    ThreadPool::defaultPool().start(worker1); 
    ThreadPool::defaultPool().start(worker2);
    // добавляем уведомления
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        queue.enqueueNotification(new WorkNotification(i));

    while (!queue.empty()) // ждем пока работы выполняются
        Poco::Thread::sleep(100);
    queue.wakeUpAll(); // говорим рабочим о выполнении
    ThreadPool::defaultPool().joinAll();
    return 0;
    }
```